# How to change value of a defined resource in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a grid in the xaml which uses a resource for its attached flyout:

```
<Grid >
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="GridFlyout"/>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

    .. other stuffs

</Grid>
```

and I have a defined resource in the page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <MenuFlyout x:Key="GridFlyout">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="delete"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="like"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="edit"/>
    </MenuFlyout>
```

But in some conditions I want to set the following resource for the above grid:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <MenuFlyout x:Key="SecondaryGridFlyout">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="like"/>
    </MenuFlyout>
```

How can I do that? thanks

Comment: @loop DataTemplateSelector doesn't work with Flyouts

Comment: In code, this should work: `FlyoutBase.SetAttachedFlyout(theGrid, (MenuFlyout) App.Current.Resources["SecondaryGridFlyout"]);` where `theGrid` represents the grid element you want to target with the new flyout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest (and fully supported) if you just do this in code. Using the attached property `AttachedFlyout`:

```
FlyoutBase.SetAttachedFlyout(theGrid, 
       (MenuFlyout) App.Current.Resources["SecondaryGridFlyout"]);
```

`theGrid` in the example above represents the `Grid` you want to change.

```
<Grid x:Name="theGrid">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="GridFlyout"/>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <!-- ... other stuff -->
</Grid>
```